# Meteor methods filereader: the argument is not a blob

Tags: meteor, filereader

I'm uploading a csv file with collectionFS and then I need to parse this file.

This is how I do:

```
Template.fsbanks.events "change .myFileInput": (event, template) ->
  FS.Utility.eachFile event, (file) ->
    Fsbanks.insert file, (err, fileObj) ->
      if err
        Notifications.danger err
      else
        console.log "File saved"
        console.log fileObj
    Meteor.call "importTransactions", file, (error, result) ->
```

Then I'd like to have some meteor methods:

```
Meteor.methods

  importTransactions: (file) ->
    reader = new FileReader
    console.log file
    reader.readAsText file
    reader.onload = (event) ->
      data = $.csv.toObjects(event.target.result)
      console.log "File read #{data}"
      _.map data, (transaction) ->
        console.log transaction
        t = {}
        date = transaction["Value date"]
        date_array = date.split("/")
        new_date = date_array[2] + "-" + date_array[1] + "-" + date_array[0]
        #          console.log new_date
        t["account_nbr"] = transaction["Account number"]
        t["value_date"] = new Date new_date
        t["amount"] = transaction["Amount in the currency of the account"].replace(/\s/g, '')
        #          console.log t["amount"]
        t["description"] = transaction["Description"]
        Meteor.call "createTransaction", t, t["Entry number"], (error, entry_nbr) ->
          if error
            console.log error
          else
            console.log id

  createTransaction: (transaction, entry_nbr) ->

    Transactions.upsert
      entry_nbr: entry_nbr
    ,
      $set: transaction

    return entry_nbr
```

When I do this, the collectionFS insert works correctly.

But I have a problem with the insertTransaction server method:

```
Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': The argument is not a Blob.
```

If I run the exact same code client side, it works.

What should I change to run the code server side?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I'm also trying to parse a file without inserting it and am having trouble. Please let me know, if you have a moment. Thanks!

Comment: It's quite old but it seems to be working. I'll put the code in the answer but honestly I don't remember what made it work.

Answer (score 0):

This the code I ended with. It's functional but I don't really know why...

In my model (shared client/server):

```
Meteor.methods

  importTransactions: (file) ->
    reader = new FileReader
    console.log file
    reader.readAsText file
    reader.onload = (event) ->
      data = $.csv.toObjects(event.target.result)
      console.log "File read #{data}"
      _.map data, (transaction) ->
        console.log transaction
        t = {}
        selectValues = {}
        date = transaction["Value date"]
        date_array = date.split("/")
        new_date = date_array[2] + "-" + date_array[1] + "-" + date_array[0]
        #          console.log new_date
        selectValues["account_nbr"] = transaction["Account number"]
        selectValues["value_date"] = new Date new_date
        selectValues["entry_nbr"] = parseInt transaction["Entry Number"]
        t["amount"] = transaction["Amount in the currency of the account"].replace(/\s/g, '')
        #          console.log t["amount"]
        t["description"] = transaction["Description"]
        Meteor.call "createTransaction", t, selectValues, (error, entry_nbr) ->
          if error
            console.log error
          else
            console.log id
```

On the server:

```
Meteor.methods
  createTransaction: (values, upsertValues) ->
    if upsertValues
      console.log "upserting transaction"
      console.log "transaction: #{values}"
      console.log "Values: #{upsertValues["entry_nbr"]}"
      Transactions.upsert upsertValues
      ,
        $set: values
      , (err, nbr) ->
        if err
          console.log err
        else
          console.log "upsert successful #{nbr}"
    else
      Transactions.insert values
      , (err, nbr) ->
        if err
          console.log err
        else
          console.log "insert successful #{nbr}"
```